# how to properly use Scoped service from c# code

Tags: c#, razor, server-side, blazor, inject

im using blazor server side and are therefore trying to use AddScoped instead of AddSingleton as the object is used on a per-user basis. I try to split the razor pages and the c# code as much as posible as i find this to be cleaner.

I add a scoped service using

```
Services.AddScoped<Services.ManageUserService>();
```

in the ConfigureServices function of the Startup class.

my problem now is to properly access the service from any .cs file (holding the logic of my .razor pages)

I have tried to do an injection like this:

```
[Inject]
public Services.ManageUserService manageUserService { get; set; }
```

and then accesed the scoped object using (username for example):

```
manageUserService.User
```

and this works. My problem is that if I add a print that is supose to only run once within the scoped service it runs every time the page is reloaded or changed.

for example, lets say i do this:

```
public class ManageUserService
{
    public string User { get; private set; }

    private bool LoadedStartup = false;

    public ManageUserService() => SetupUser();

    private void SetupUser()
    {
        if (!LoadedStartup)
        {
            User = "me";
            LoadedStartup = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("User:" + User);
        }
    }
}
```

I then access the class from multiply .cs files using:

```
[Inject]
public Services.ManageUserService manageUserService { get; set; }
```

The print *"User:me"* is supposed to only happen once as the locking bool *LoadedStartup* is changed, problem is that I get the print every time the Inject is happening *(on change page, etc)*

What am I doing wrong? aren't the AddScoped() suppose to add a "singelton" instance for every client? am I accessing it wrongly?

I can't find any examples of using AddScoped from separated .cs and .razor pages, only directly from the .razor page, and then it is done using *@inject*.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation:

1.- Add the scoped services:

```
Services.AddScoped<Services.ManageUserService>();
```

2.- Then, in order to have really the scoped instances once per user, in _Hosts.cshtml:

```
<app>
 <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
</app>
```

3.- Now the trick I found by myself, instance the scoped services in App.razor

```
@inject Examples.ViewModels.MainViewModel Main;
@inject Examples.ViewModels.ChildViewModel Child;
@inject Examples.ViewModels.LayoutViewModel Layout;
@inject Examples.ViewModels.TreeViewModel Tree;
@{

Child.Main = Main;
Tree.LayoutViewModel = Layout;
}
```

4.- And if you have in the constructor something like:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
  public static MainViewModel Instance;
  public MainViewModel()
  {
  Instance = this;
 }

}
```

You can access to any class you define as service from anywhere in your code.

```
 MainViewModel.Instance...
```

I post about it at my blog: https://expediteapps.net/2020/02/18/scoped-viewmodels-instanced-once-on-start/

Comment: thats a rly nice answere to a problem thats been driving me mad (and rly should be easy to solve), will try it out and accept it if it works! thank you!